# How to Create Token based Router in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

I want to create Custom API through controller action.

How i can authenticate using token to make secure API.

**Example:**

http://www.example.com/webapiv1/getItems

http://www.example.com/webapiv1/getOrders

Answer (score 0):

You can use admin token for authentication 
To generate admin token
        a) Url - http://www.example.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token
        b) Type - POST
        c) Parameters - username, password
           Username - your-admin-username
           Password - your-passord